# Do vector fields on manifold have to be defined using derivatives?

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

In my (physics) manifolds lecture notes they define vector fields using the product rule, rather than explicitly defining them as derivatives.

Are there any other ways therefore of defining vector fields which are not the usual derivatives that satisfy this product rule?

Comment: One way:  a vector field is a section of the tangent bundle.

Comment: Vector fields are (smooth) sections of $TM:=\bigsqcup_{p\in M} T_pM$.

Comment: But would these not be equivalent to the partial derivative definition? Apologies, I come from a physics background

Comment: Yes, they're all equivalent.

Comment: There's no way to avoid derivatives:  a vector field is to be tangent to the manifold, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is slickest and most efficient to define a vector field as a linear operator $\mathcal{X}: C^\infty(M) \to C^\infty(M)$ satisfying the product rule. However, this is not exactly intuitive, and there are alternate constructions.

One of the most "concrete" of these is to define a vector at a point $p \in M$ as an equivalence class of smooth curves. That is, every such curve determines a unique tangent vector at $p$, namely the tangent vector to the curve. Two curves are considered equivalent if they determine the same tangent vector, and we write $\gamma \sim \alpha$ for $\gamma,\alpha: [-1,1] \to M$ such that $\gamma(0) = \alpha(0) = p$ if, in every chart $u: U \to \mathbb{R}^n$, where $U$ is an open subset of $M$, we have $(u \circ \gamma)'(0) = (u \circ \alpha)'(0)$. (In fact, it is sufficient to check this condition in just a single chart.)

Here's a rough sketch of the picture I drew in Krita:

[image: Depiction of equivalence classes of curves determining a tangent vector]